# Count number of rows from one table that have exactly one related row in foreign table

Tags: sqlite, count, foreign-keys, relationship

Let's say table_A has a one-to-many relation with table_B.
So table_B has a foreign key that points to the `id` column of table_A and it can have multiple records pointing to the same `id`

How can I count the number of rows from table_A (or table_B, it doesn't matter it's the same number) that have exactly one related record in table_B and not more?

I need this to calculate the bounce rate. My tables represent a visitor session and a page view and sessions can have one or more page views. Bounce rate = sessions with a single page view / total page views

Answer (score 0):

The Below query should give you the list of pageIds that have association to only one session

> select p.sessionId from sessions s , page p where s.id = p.SessionId
>   group by p.SessionId having count(p.sessionId)=1;